# Conditionally load content script into a Safari extension like in FF/Chrome?

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, safari-extension, content-script

I'm writing a reasonably complex browser extension for Chrome, Firefox & Safari.

In Chrome & Firefox, I can specify which content script are injected into which sites based on URL matching.

Safari doesn't appear to offer any such (fine grained) functionality – they only allow one white/blacklist for all sites.

Is there a way to do this? If not, how can I conditionally load a Javascript file? (bearing in mind I can't add them to the DOM).

I've tried [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/), but it appends to the DOM.

Note: I don't want to add logic to the actual files, as they are essentially library code that's duplicated across the extensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`safari.extension.addContentScript` and `safari.extension.addContentScriptFromURL` allow you to programmatically inject scripts. You can use these methods in either your global page, an extension popover, or an extension bar. For both methods, the arguments are:

- the script to inject (as a string or as a URL, respectively),
- a whitelist of URL patterns to match pages on which to inject the script,
- a blacklist to exclude pages, and
- a boolean for whether to inject the script as an end script (or else as a start script).

See [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ExtensionClassRef/SafariExtension.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009681) in the Safari Extensions Reference for details.

Note that the whitelist and blacklist both use a URL pattern format that is similar (but not identical) to UNIX wildcards and is not nearly so powerful as regular expresssions. This pattern format is described at the bottom of [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionPermissions/ExtensionPermissions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH8-SW1).

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I couldn't find that.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is correct but it's important to note that you cannot programatically inject scripts into currently open tabs like Chrome and Firefox can. The [SafariExtension Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ExtensionClassRef/SafariExtension.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009681) states:

> **Adding and removing style sheets and scripts.** Adding or removing a content style sheet applies to pages immediately. Adding or removing a content script applies only to pages opened or reloaded after that point. Removing a style sheet or a script that is in the Info.plist file removes it only from the current browser session.

Because of this limitation, it's often easier to simply rely on the `Scripts` attribute in `Info.plist` instead.

Comment: But isn't `Info.plist` the "one white/blacklist" that OP was complaining about?

Comment: Indeed it is, @Teepeemm. My point was to make it clear that `addContentScript` and `addContentScriptFromURL` have the severe limitation of not being able to affect open tabs. I (and apparently others) had stumbled upon this question thinking it allowed true dynamic loading.